# JBoss AS 6 multiple ejb jars in same war - how to config?

Tags: jboss, jar, ejb, ejb-3.0, war

I am trying to figure out how to configure my war so that it successfully deploys all my EJBs (EJB 3)in JBoss.  The EJBs are found in multiple jars within the war.

Could you show me an example on how to config this?  In other words, what is the file that I need to edit so that JBoss knows that there are multiple jars containing EJBs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use EAR archive to deploy multi-module application (with many EJBs). The JBoss deployer for WAR files and directories dont' analyse WEB-INF/lib directory for any EJBs and don't deploy it. Only simple classes will be loaded from this directory. You can deploy all EJBs separately of course.

For EAR archive you should specify application.xml file and you may specify jboss-app.xml with deployment information. For example,

```
<application>
  <display-name>My Application</display-name>

  <module>
     <web>
        <web-uri>web-app.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>/myapp</context-root>
     </web>
  </module>

  <module>
     <ejb>ejb-app.jar</ejb>
  </module>
</application>
```

Here a [link](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/JBoss_Deployer_Architecture-Deployers_and_ClassLoaders.html) to JBoss 4 Server Configuration Guide. I haven't found the same content in documentation for AS 6. But probably the main deployer concept is the same.

Comment: For J2EE 6(!) (see Weld as reference implementation) you can deploy EJB with WAR. See [Packaging Enterprise Beans in WAR Modules](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipio.html#gippi)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything special to deploy your EJBs in a war file. As long as your POJOs are annotated with `@Stateless` / `@Stateful` it should be fine. You obviously need to place your EJB jar files in `WEB-INF/lib` and that should be enough.

Are you seeing any specific errors or experiencing problems? If so, what JBoss version are you using? If you update your question with this information I can update my answer accordingly.